# How to process the output redirection data into the e-mail getting it appended on the list

Tags: python, email

How to process the python list data into the mail function of MIME. Below is the script which looks for the "`sshd`" process on the system and based the condition applied like if its running more than 30 mins then it reports back via an e-mail.

I'm using "`cStringIO`" module for the redirection purpose So the data can be hold on the `data_stream` variable to which i can call into the mail send function. So, when i runs the script it works on the console correctly but the e-mail it sends into the different parts, I have quoted the example below soon after the script code..

> Problem Summary:

as in the below test example when i ran the scripts it runs okay on the command console but when it processed via the e-mail it send those 4 different e-mail notes ..

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import subprocess
import socket
import sys
import cStringIO
import re
mylist = list()

hst_name = (socket.gethostname())
def checK_ps():
    ps = subprocess.Popen(['ps', '-eo' 'pid,user,args,etime='], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = ps.communicate()[0]
    for line in output.splitlines():
         result = re.search(".*[\/\s]+(sshd:)\s+", line)
         if result:
             time_items = re.split('-|:',(line.split(' ')[-1]))
             time_len = len(time_items)
             mystdout = sys.stdout
             data_stream = cStringIO.StringIO()
             sys.stdout = data_stream

             if  time_len == 4:
                 print "Alert sshd: is running longer on the host",hst_name,time_items[0],"days:" #  "-->",line.strip()

             elif time_len == 3:
                 print "Alert sshd: is running longer on the host",hst_name,time_items[-3],"hours:" # "-->",line.strip()

             elif time_len == 2 and int(time_items[-2]) >= 30:
                 print "Alert sshd: is running longer on the host",hst_name,time_items[-2],"minutes:" #, "-->",line.strip()

             sys.stdout = mystdout
             variable_data = data_stream.getvalue()
             xxx = variable_data + line.strip() + "\n\n"
             mylist.append(xxx)
             mailp = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-t", "-oi"], stdin=PIPE)
             msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
             msg['To'] = "karn@example.com"
             msg['Subject'] = "Daily PS Check Report"
             msg['From'] = "systemHealth@example.com"
             msg1 = MIMEText(xxx,  'text')
             msg.attach(msg1)
             mailp.communicate(msg.as_string())
    print "".join([str(x) for x in mylist] )
checK_ps()
```

> Example: test run of the script:
>
> Main problem is that all below "Alerts" are going into 4 different emails which should be one as they all the process from same system.

$ ./testps.py
    Alert sshd: is running longer on the host root-karn 01 hours:
    4536 root     sshd: karn [priv]              01:03:21

```
Alert sshd: is running longer on the host root-karn 01 hours:
4621 karn     sshd: karn@pts/1               01:03:11

Alert sshd: is running longer on the host root-karn 20 hours:
20124 root     sshd: niraj [priv]             20:16:06

Alert sshd: is running longer on the host root-karn 20 hours:
20130 niraj    sshd: niraj@pts/2              20:16:05
```

Now, i have tried to append the list and process it but it looks same above, i'm curious to know how it can be processed into single email.

> Requirement :
>   To have single e-mail from single Server when it runs there and catch's the process.

Appreciate any hist and suggestion.

Comment: @ I wish to have really an expert advise  on the above Post please.

Comment: you send an e-mail each time you find a result. You will have to take the sending out of the `for`-loop

Comment: One way would be to split the functionality between 2 methods. One method which checks the open processes, and returns a `list`, `dict` or whather coollection you choose to transfer the results. A second method which takes this collection, assembles the e-mail and sends it.

Comment: @MaartenFabré, thnx for your revert, i tried to work through tuple & lists but still did not come around the solution. "`xxx = variable_data + line.strip() + "\n\n"`"  <-- this is where i need to work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to split your script into different sections, each with a dedicated task.

## Imports

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import subprocess
import socket
import re
```

## Gathering the events

```
def _read_ps()
    with subprocess.Popen(['ps', '-eo' 'pid,user,args,etime='], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as ps:
        messages = list()
        for line in output.splitlines():
            if re.search(".*[\/\s]+(sshd:)\s+", line):
                time_items = re.split('-|:',(line.split(' ')[-1]))
                time_len = len(time_items)

                message = ""
                if time_len in (3, 4,) or (time_len == 2 & int(time_items[0] >= 30)):
                    message = "Alert sshd: is running longer on the host %s %s days:" % hst_name,time_items[0]
                messages.append("".join(message, line.strip, '\n\n'))
    return messages
```

`lst[-3]` if the `len(lst) == 3` is the same as `lst[0]`, so that portion could be simplified

You redirected `sys.stdout` to print the message, but that could've been easier with `print >> buffer, message` than the way you do it now, and even that method is not as simple as string formatting for the purpose you used it

## Compiling the mail-message

The result of the previous method is a list of messages to send. This method compiles this into one e-mail if there are any messages. I'm not familiar with compiling e-mail on Python, so this might need some work.

```
def _construct_message(messages):
    if not messages: # no messages to send
        return None
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['To'] = "karn@example.com"
    msg['Subject'] = "Daily PS Check Report"
    msg['From'] = "systemHealth@example.com"
    for message in messages:
        msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'text')
    return msg
```

Instead of the for-loop you could replace the last 3 lines with something like this:

```
return msg.attach(MIMEText'\n'.join(messages), 'text')
```

but i'm not too familiar with e-mail

## Sending the e-mail

Once the e-mail message is compiled, you need to send it

```
def _send_mail(mail_message):
    with Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-t", "-oi"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE) as mailp:
        mailp.communicate(mail_message.as_string())
```

## Tying it together

```
def check_ps():
    messages = _read_ps()
    mail_message = _construct_message(messages)
    if mail_message:
        _send_mail(mail_message)
```

The advantage of splitting the work into little pieces is that you can more easily debug and test each of the individual methods

## Context managers

`Popen` can be used as a context manager using the `with` statement. This way you the connection gets closed correctly, even if something goes wrong along the way

Comment: many thanks for giving your precious time and workaround on the post, though i have achieved that with file object  creation. I'm sorry i don't have much privileges to up-vote  your answer, its worth appreciable.

Comment: What did you achieve with file creation? and if it works, you can accept it. If it doesn't work, let me know where I can help to further improve it

Comment: i got the solution myself and i just posted the whole code below. I did not check your answer yet , i'll check and accept if will work.

Comment: @ Maarten Fabre,  i have accepted the answer based on the approach you given i have not tested yet. but the logic and time you have given to me i appreciate that in real regards!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone looking on the post to inculcate your ideas and views if any, i worked with different way around and got my solution!

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import subprocess
import socket
import sys
import os
import re

hst_name = (socket.gethostname())
def checK_ps():
    ps = subprocess.Popen(['ps', '-eo' 'pid,user,args,etime='], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = ps.communicate()[0]
    for line in output.splitlines():
         #if len(re.findall('\\b'+line+'\\b', "rm", flags=re.IGNORECASE))>0:
         result = re.search(".*[\/\s]+(rm)\s+", line)
         #result = re.search(".*[\/|\s]+(rm)\s+", line)
         if result:
             time_items = re.split('-|:',(line.split(' ')[-1]))
             time_len = len(time_items)
             print_stdout = sys.stdout
             print_output = open('/tmp/ps_msg', 'a')
             sys.stdout = print_output
             if  time_len == 4:
                 print "Alert rm is running longer on the host",hst_name,time_items[0],"days:" + "\n" + line.strip()
                 print ""

             #elif time_len == 3:
             elif time_len == 3 and int(time_items[-3]) >= 02:
                 print "Alert rm is running longer on the host",hst_name,time_items[-3],"hours:" + "\n" +  line.strip()
                 print ""

             elif time_len == 2 and int(time_items[-2]) >= 05:
                 print "Alert rm is running longer on the host",hst_name,time_items[-2],"minutes:" + "\n" + line.strip()
                 print ""

             sys.stdout = print_stdout
             print_output.close()
checK_ps()

############ Process capturing part done above #################
############ File comparison & sendmail part starts here ########

def ps_Mail():
    filename = "/tmp/ps_msg"
    f = file(filename)
    if os.path.exists(filename) and os.path.getsize(filename) > 0:
        mailp = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-t", "-oi"], stdin=PIPE)
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['To'] = "karn@example.com"
        msg['Subject'] = "Uhh!! Unsafe rm process Seen"
        msg['From'] = "psCheck@example.com"
        msg1 = MIMEText(f.read(),  'text')
        msg.attach(msg1)
        mailp.communicate(msg.as_string())
ps_Mail()

###########  Clean the file after Sending an E-mail  ############
os.unlink("/tmp/ps_msg")
```